# Search only part of a document in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I have documents in marklogic which contains many elements with different namespaces. 
Is there anyway to search only elements with specific namespace. I mean we do not want whole document to be searchable. Only part of the documents can be searched and the part which is searchable can be identified with namespace.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of a way to constrain just by namespace, other than using XPath instead of search. If the number of elements is finite, and not changing, using fields could be an option. You'd have to create a field for each namespace, and list all elements in that namespace explicitly, but it does give you a way to search across a selection of elements or paths that could be scattered across the document.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your specific use case in detail from your description.  However, you may find [phrase-around](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin-help/phrase-around) and [phrase-through](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin-help/phrase-through) and [element-word-query-through](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin-help/element-word-query-through) to be your friends for certain use-cases.